# EF Core 5: migrations with TPT

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

Allow this one to ask someone help this one.

This one is moving my DB app into EF Core from SQLalchemy.

Because EF Core supports table-per-type (joined table inheritance).

I show my code　below

Class

```
public class Degreaser_Old
{
    public Degreaser_Old()
    { }

    public Degreaser_Old(string tubname)
    {
        ChemistryContext Context = ContextMaker.MainContext();
        DegreaserPosNavigation = Context.DegreaserPos
                                        .Include(s => s.Degreaser)
                                        .SingleOrDefault(s => s.EngName == tubname);
    }

    public int DegreaserCode { get; set; }
    public int SarogateKey { get; set; }
    public int DegreaserPos { get; set; }
    public double DegreaserConc { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public DegreaserPos DegreaserPosNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual MeasureDay SarogateKeyNavigation { get; set; }
}

public class Degreaser : Degreaser_Old
{
    public Degreaser()
    { }

    public Degreaser(string tubname) : base(tubname)
    { }

    public decimal Level { get; protected set; }
    public decimal Volume { get; protected set; }
}
```

Context configuration (fluent API)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Degreaser_Old>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("Degreaser");
            entity.HasKey(e => e.DegreaserCode);

            entity.HasAlternateKey(a => new { a.SarogateKey, a.DegreaserPos });

            entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.SarogateKey, e.DegreaserPos })
                                        .IsUnique(true);
            entity.HasDiscriminator(c => c.Type)
                .HasValue<Degreaser_Old>("Old")
                .HasValue<Degreaser>("Degreaser");
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.SarogateKey)
                .HasDatabaseName("Degreaser$測定日コード");
            entity.Property(e => e.DegreaserCode).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            entity.Property(e => e.DegreaserConc).HasPrecision(5, 2);
            entity.Property(e => e.DegreaserPos).HasColumnName("Degreaser_Pos");
            entity.Property(e => e.DegreaserCode).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            entity.Property(e => e.Type);
            entity.HasOne(d => d.DegreaserPosNavigation)
                .WithMany(p => p.Degreaser)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.DegreaserPos)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("Degreaser${8BC67109-2594-4BBD-848F-EB4D77039677}");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.SarogateKeyNavigation)
                .WithMany(p => p.Degreasers)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.SarogateKey)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("Degreaser${5C8E5635-10BD-4124-8D13-FCC511573DC5}");
        });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Degreaser>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("Degreaser_Vol");
            entity.HasBaseType<Degreaser_Old>();
            entity.Property(c => c.Level).HasMaxLength(5);
            entity.Property(c => c.Volume).HasPrecision(4,2);
        });
```

Message at running Add-Migrations

> 'Degreaser' is mapped to the table 'Degreaser_Vol' while 'Degreaser_Old' is mapped to the table 'Degreaser'. Map all the entity types in the hierarchy to the same table or remove the discriminator and map all of them to different tables. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2130430 for more information.

This one can understand this statement says that you must use TPH or TPC.

But this one does not have enough knowledge to solve it.

This problem is over my head.

Comment: *"...or **remove the discriminator** and map all of them to different tables"* -  Remove the discriminator is the key. You must remove `entity.HasDiscriminator(..)` line. Only TPH uses discriminator, TPT is based purely on left outer joins.

Comment: I misunderstood discriminator in each ORM. 
I added discriminator to keep compatibility between EF core 5 and SQLalchemy. But it prebented migration.